# How do I remove a role from an EC2 instance?

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I launched an instance with an iam role

I now want to remove the role from the instance via powershell

I must be confused about the terminology here because I'm reading [this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_manage_delete.html) and I don't see how to remove a role from an instance.

I want to run this command on the EC2 instance that the role will be removed from.

There can only be one role assigned to an instance so is there a way to dynamically get the iam role that has been assigned to an instance and remove it from the instance via the powershell api?

Comment: Removing a role from a running instance doesn't really seem to make sense... if you could do that, the instance would never again have a role, because you can't add one back, later.  What's the application for this?

Comment: You cannot do tha from instance settings, I would suggest try deleting role form IAM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that using AWS CLI (`v1.11.46` or newer).

You can disassociate an IAM instance profile from a running or stopped instance using the `disassociate-iam-instance-profile` command.

See the [disassociate-iam-instance-profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/disassociate-iam-instance-profile.html) CLI command documentation for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change (add or remove) IAM Roles on an instance once it has been created. This is a limitation of the EC2 service and is the same no matter which CLI you use so it isn't just powershell that cannot do this.

You have to re-create the instance with new roles if you want to change them.

Answer (score 3):

Adding and changing Roles on EC2 instances is now (early 2017) supported via the CLI or Console.

You can just remove a role via the CLI `remove-role-from-instance-profile`  or via the console by replacing the old with the offered "No Role" option.

Comment: Here is the AWS guide on Replacing An IAM Role with various different approaches, both in console and cli.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#replace-iam-role